# how to check if the / operator has no remainder in C？

Tags: c, operator-keyword

I want to check `if` the `/` operator has no remainder or not:

```
int x = 0;    
if (x = 16 / 4), if there is no remainder: 
   then  x = x - 1;
if (x = 16 / 5), if remainder is not zero:
   then  x = x + 1;
```

How to check if there are remainder in `C`? and
How to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find the remainder of an integer division then you can use the modulus(`%`):

```
if( 16 % 4 == 0 )
{
   x = x - 1 ;
}
else
{
   x = x +1 ;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Frist, you need `%` remainder operator:

```
if (x = 16 % 4){
     printf("remainder in X");
}
```

Note: it will not work with float/double, in that case you need to use [`fmod (double numer, double denom);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/).

Second, to implement it as you wish:

1. `if (x = 16 / 4)`, if there is no remainder, `x = x - 1`;
2. `If (x = 16 / 5)`, then `x = x + 1`;

Useing `,` comma operator, you can do it in single step as follows (read comments):

```
int main(){
  int x = 0,   // Quotient.
      n = 16,  // Numerator
      d = 4;   // Denominator
               // Remainder is not saved
  if(x = n / d, n % d) // == x = n / d; if(n % d)
    printf("Remainder not zero, x + 1 = %d", (x + 1));
  else
    printf("Remainder is zero,  x - 1 = %d", (x - 1));
  return 1;
}
```

Check working codes @codepade: [first](http://codepad.org/QVsITqDf), [second](http://codepad.org/jNUMkkk3), [third](http://codepad.org/GBBscI5Q).
Notice in if-condition I am using Comma Operator: `,`, to understand `,` operator read: [comma operator with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785206/why-does-this-c-code-compile-what-does-it-do/17785232#17785232).

Answer (score 3):

use the % operator to find the remainder of a division

```
if (number % divisor == 0)
{
//code for perfect divisor
}
else
{
//the number doesn't divide perfectly by divisor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **modulous operator** for this purpose.

`if(x%y == 0)` then there is no remainder.

In division operation, if the result is floating point, then only integer part will be returned and decimal part will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Modulous operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) which deals with remainder.

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator (represented by the % symbol in C) computes the remainder. So:

```
x = 16 % 4;
```

x will be 0.

```
X = 16 % 5;
```

x will be 1