# Can't understand the output of C progaram

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x=10,y=12;
  printf("%d",(x,y));
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is 12. How?

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and why?

Comment: What do you expect it to be?  Why? (wow Slaks - I swear that wasn't intentional)

Comment: Related: [Using Comma operator in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666095/using-comma-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression that you are evaluating is:

```
x,y
```

This expression uses the **comma operator**. The standard (*6.5.17 Comma operator*) says:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

So, in your code, `x,y` evaluates to `y`, which has a value of `12`.

For a more expansive discussion, I refer you to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). Although that discusses C++, the discussion for this operator is valid in the context of C. Particularly relevant to your question is this section:

> The comma in various comma-separated lists, such as function argument lists (`f(a, b, c)`), initializer lists `int a[] = {1,2,3}`, or initialization statements (`int i, j;`) is not the comma operator. If the comma operator needs to be used in that context, it has to be parenthesized: `f(a, (n++, n+b), c)`.

And that's exactly the situation in your question. If you had written:

```
printf("%d", x, y);
```

then there would have been no use of the comma operator, and you would have supplied one more argument to `printf` than format specifier.

Answer (score 4):

You're by chance using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

In the C and C++ programming languages, the **comma operator** (represented by the token `,`) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

That said,

```
printf("%d",(x,y));
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
printf("%d", y);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because first (x,y) is evaluated.
inside () the expression is x,y they are evaluated from left to right since the Associativity of `Comma` operator is `left to right`,  so the last value of evaluating (x,y) is y.
read `operator precedence and associativity rule` and how expressions are evaluated under operator precedence to understand these type of expressions

Comment: Can you provide any link to read operator precedence and associativity rule ?

Comment: @user3416257 you just want table then check [this](http://n.ethz.ch/~werdemic/download/week3/C++%20Precedence.html) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx). go through some expression evaluation examples too.