# What does ',' means in if syntax?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I was looking on some examples and I don't know what this means:

```
if(FileExistsA("File.ext"), false)
{
     ....
}
```

Can someone explain me this please?

Comment: It has no special meaning in `if`, it's the same as its meaning in any other expression.

Comment: Most likely this was done to "comment out" the `if` statement without removing the call to FileExistsA or significantly altering the formatting of the source.  I think most folks would have used `&& false` instead, as it's a bit more obvious, and a more conscientious programmer would have added some sort of comment (with attention-getting flags) to indicate what had been done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C and C++ (but not C# or Java), [the comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) '`,`' evaluates both the left and right expressions, but only returns the right expression.

In this example:

```
bool x = (true, false);
// x == false

bool y = (false, false, true)
// y == true
```

In your case, `if( FileExistsA("File.ext"), false )` will never follow its branch because the comma operator ensures that `false` is the result.

**Update** I forgot about the precedence of `=` and `,`. I've wrapped the expressions above in parenthesis to prevent the expression from being evaluated as `(bool x = true), false === false`.

Comment: Rather stupid abuse of the operator in the OPs example, though. Better not use it...

Comment: And may be `, fasle` was added during during debugging, or to fix some bug

Comment: +1 I can't accept your answer for now ... 8 min left. but who wants to use this stupid thing?

Comment: @Dai, branch can be executed but if before it we have line: #define false true :)

Comment: @Quest you may like to read this [What is the proper use of the comma operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902992/what-is-the-proper-use-of-the-comma-operator)

Comment: *" ... but only returns the right expression."*. Not necessarily; it could return anything depending on the types of the operands. In case of built-in types, it returns the rightmost expression, but for user-defined types, the return value depends on how `,` is implemented.

Comment: @dai I removed my upvote for time being ..  correct comment In `bool x = true, false;`  `x` would be `true` *not* `false`,  `x = (true, false);`give `false` read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17785232/1673391) correct it I will up-vote again.

Comment: -1. Also, your examples are wrong. Please verify the results and your claim!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I've corrected my answer, thank you for pointing out the error.

Comment: @Dai upvoted but still  I'm not at all convinced by your statement `",' evaluates both the left and right expressions."`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan consider `x = ( Foo(), Bar() );` with both `int Foo() { return 1; } int Bar() { return 2; }`. If you set a debugger breakpoint in both functions, you'll see both are called.